# Working out the Probability of a Sum in Elimination Dice Mechanics

Tags: probability, dice

I'm trying to work out the Probability of getting X on 7d6 (7 6 Sided Dice) with a single dice elimination after failing to get a specific result need to attack or loss through game play.

OK working on a dice Game that requires a players roll specific results in order to gain a card, Currently using symbols on the Dice, but for simplicities sake numbers 1-3 work as unique sets, with the Sum required, I.e a player needs a Sum of X Min 1 Max 8, or chance of getting Sums of 2, to 8, I.e player needs 2 and 6 on 7d6 from (1-3)

And the chances of getting on 7d6 5/6's with set results like say two 5's, and 6 on 7d6

However this is complicated by the need of elimination within the game where if you fail to roll any of the needed combination i.e three 3's or 1-3 dice rolls upto the sum of , or two 5's or two 6's then the player only rolls 6d6 (6 6Sided Dice) next time to try and get the results then 5d6 (5 6Sided Dice), 4d6 etc. Or where the game requires the loss of Dice as they are placed on the potential captured card.

So for example,
Ok its a game within a game, so have a habit of forgetting others not familiar and did not explain properly with hindsight, apologise.
using D6's (Six sided Dice) and each has 6 symbols on them (1 Sword, 2 Sword, 3 Sword, Political, Castle, wizard) Broken down numbers 1,2,3 are swords and in that strength, Political is number 4, Castle is number 5, and Wizard is number 6.

Ok so players have a series of cards laid out on the table and they need to roll combinations of Dice in order to match up specific results to obtain the Card.

So if the Player decides they wish to take Priest Card, they would need 4 Swords, 1 Sword, 1 Political, and One Castle.
The player rolls 7d6 and gets a 3 Swords, 1 Sword, Priest, Priest, 3 Swords, Castle, 2 Swords, So they place the 3 swords, 3 swords and the 1 Sword on the Card completing the Swords requirement, and reroll now 4d6 as three are placed on the Priest Card.

The next rolls are all swords, so the player looses a single Dice and re-rolls 3D6.

They get 3, priests, and so take one to complete the Priest requirement leaving 2d6 to play.

They roll 2d6, getting a 3-Swords and a Wizard, so fail to complete the card requirements.

Their are other mechanics in play with cards that alter conditions but just need help with this aspect as not an intuitive mathematician and so need some help.

Comment: If you're just interested in the probability, then you can get a fair estimation by coding up your scenario and then iterating until you get a stable result.

Comment: The problem one has is that I am not sure whether this is just a case of probabilities and adding each chance of getting X(d)Requirement for each throw of a decreasing dice set or something much more complex, as this is an area of maths one has not covered indepth before.